# JavaFX - Listen to when the layout creation is complete

Tags: javafx

Is there a way to listen to when the layout creation is complete?

Several times I have ran into an issue where I needed to wait until a Group has been completely created along with all its children.
For comparison on Android each View (Node) has a method [onFinishInflate()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#onFinishInflate()). From doc:

> This is called as the last phase of inflation, after all child views have been added

I did not find any method like this in JavaFX nor any other suitable way to listen to such event.

Comment: No - no such event is generated. This seems like an x-y question: you're asking about the wrong solution to whatever problem it is you're trying to solve.

Comment: @James_D Thanks and yes you are right, this is not what I am trying to solve right now, but I still find it strange that such event does not exist here.

Comment: It's not particularly strange. The way JavaFX is designed, there's no need for it.

Comment: You need to spend some time leaning `JavaFX` and how it works. You should not expect two different programming languages to be the same.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions and thought. I don't expect them to be the same but I can clearly see similarities.

Answer (score 0):

I came accross similar problem when I tries to get localToScreen bounds of some node. Until that node was not fully laid out on screen it return everytime NaN for the respective pixel coordinates

So what I'm doing is in the MainApp:

```
MyController myController = loader.getController();
stage.setOnShown(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {
        
        @Override
        public void handle(WindowEvent arg0) {
            myController.windowIsShown();
            
        }
});
stage.show();
```

In this way I get notified when everything is displayed on screen and laid out.